# Calling REST POST Service from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, http-headers

I am using "request" node module to call third party REST services.

Here is my sample code:

```
request.post({url:'https://myyrl/myfunction', formData: formData,  function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err)
        resolve({"message": err});
    else
        resolve({"message": body});
})
```

By this I am getting error as "The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.".

Please help me how to pass headers to this request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.post({url:'https://myurl/myfunction', body: formData, json: true, headers: {'contentType': 'application/json'}}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err)
        resolve({"message": err});
    else
        resolve({"message": JSON.stringify(body)});
});
```

Worked for me...